# Add option is not coming for adding build in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

[image: see plus button is not coming for selecting build][image: this is screen shot where plus button is not coming for adding build]

Somebody please help me i am searching this problem from 3 days .

Comment: What is the problem ? Did you submit a build of your binary IPA file using app launcher on mac ?

Comment: @Sachin Singh, have you upload your `.ipa` file use Application Loader or Xcode?

Comment: before 1 month i uploaded one  basic build  . After that  i remove from ready for sale . Now i am uploading latest build that fully tested from test team .

Comment: I am uploading it from x code 7 .

Comment: Was the binary .ipa file upload successful ? Did you get any error messages or warnings ?

Comment: Please see first image ..here plus button is not comping for selecting the build .. I created one new version  for latest build .

Comment: No i didn't get any  error message . message was coming  successfully uploaded to App store

Comment: I just notices that you are looking under "Apple watch" - have you uploaded a binary for apple watch ?

Comment: This is very critical build i have to upload to app store . From 3 days i am struggling like anything .

Comment: No this an i phone and i pad application

Comment: try to use application loader for uploading your app and try to change the version of your app before upload it

Comment: I tried but .Still same problem ...

Comment: Finally its came .I noticed that i was using team account while uploading archive from Xcode thank you guys .  @FahadJamal @ Koby Douek

Answer (score -1):

Finally its came .I noticed that i was using team account while uploading archive from Xcode after that i tried company account. So add button came .  thank you guys .  @FahadJamal @ Koby Douek